# Why is my controller config not allowing a cross-origin call?

Tags: javascript, java, angular, spring, spring-mvc

I get this error message in my Browser Console, even though I think everything should be working. I´m just starting out with all of this, so I would be very gratefull if someone could help me out here.

Error: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/api/file/upload/. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

This is my Post-Method in the Controller:

```
   @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", maxAge = 3600, allowCredentials="true")
    @PostMapping("/upload/")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> uploadBild(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                                             @AuthenticationPrincipal User user,
                                             HttpServletResponse response) {
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
        System.out.println("File received Upload: " + file);
        String[] allowedTypes = {"image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/png"};

        if (!Arrays.asList(allowedTypes).contains(file.getContentType())) {
            Map<String, String> responseBody = new HashMap<>();
            responseBody.put("error", "Invalid file type. Only jpeg and png files are allowed");
            return new ResponseEntity<>(responseBody, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        PictureDTO pictureDTO = new PictureDTO();
        pictureDTO.setTitle(file.getOriginalFilename());
        Picture picture = pictureService.save(pictureDTO, user);

        if (uploadService.saveFile(file, picture.getId())){
            Map<String, String> response1 = new HashMap<>();
            response1.put("message", "File uploaded successfully");
            return new ResponseEntity<>(response1, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        else {
            Map<String, String> response2 = new HashMap<>();
            response2.put("message", "File upload failed");
            return new ResponseEntity<>(response2, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }

    }
```

These are my application.properties:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://user1:pass1@localhost:27017/?authSource=db1&replicaSet=rs1
spring.data.mongodb.database=db1
com.example.demo.accessTokenExpirationMinutes=5
com.example.demo.refreshTokenExpirationDays=30
accessTokenSecret=12345
refreshTokenSecret=54321
spring.web.cors.enabled=true
spring.web.cors.allow-origin=http://localhost:4200
spring.web.cors.allow-credentials=true
```

This is my WebSecurityConfiguration:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(accessTokenEntryPoint).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.addFilterBefore(accessTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

And this is my frontend API Call:

```
  uploadFile(file: File) {

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);

    this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/api/file/upload/', formData,{headers: {"Content-Type":"multipart/form-data"}}).subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response);
      // this.watermarkImage(file, "COPYRIGHT")

    });
  }
```

I hope this is enough information. Thank you very much! Best regards!

Comment: CORS needs to be enabled on Server APIS.

Comment: @VimalPatel - The OP appears to be trying to do just that, look at the first line of the first code block.

Comment: Your `@CrossOrigin` attribute allows the origin `http://localhost:4200`. Is that in fact the origin of the page running the `this.http.post` call?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I´m using Spring on the Server-Side.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sorry, I missed out on that, I guess Access-Control-Allow-Methods header is missing in that. which should mention POST method as well

Comment: @VimalPatel - I'd assume the `@CrossOrigin` annotation handles the headers (but then it's not clear why the code does them explicitly later as well), but I haven't done this in Spring, so... :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  - I´ve added the headers explicitly as a way to try and fix the problem, but that didn´t seem to change anything. They are still in the code though, because Chat GPT recommended them to, when I asked there and left them out.

Comment: LOL I wouldn't trust ChatGPT to give you good coding advice. It's a human language model, not a programming service. It will readily give you very convincing nonsense. :-)